# Pass uipickerview row title to a function

Tags: ios, function, uipickerview

so i created a weather app.

It has a text field where user types the city and then click the button.

The city name will be passed to a function that will request a data for this city.
I have passed the city name to this function

```
-(void)getCurrent:(NSString *)query
```

by this way

```
[theWeather getCurrent:self.TextField.text];
```

But now i decided to change text field to uipickerview and i got stuck

How can i pass the selected row in my picker view to this function ?

Comment: So what data is actually in the UIPickerView?

Comment: @soulshined the array of lists
    _pickerData = @[@"Toronto", @"Waterloo", @"Vancouver", @"Montreal", @"Quebec", @"Calgary", @"Ottawa", @"Edmonton", @"Mississauga", @"Winnipeg", @"Brampton", @"Hamilton"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your selected row by accessing the array:

You can get it in the following manner:

```
NSInteger row;
row = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

getCurrent:_pickerData[row]
```

Comment: hey so it didnt work. 

it works only like this 

    [theWeather getCurrent:_pickerData[0]];
theWeather is for accessing function in another file weather

so this worked, but it returned me the weather conditions in the specific city Toronto which index is 0 in pickerData array. 

do you know how not to hard code the index ?

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @([self.PickerView selectedRowInComponent:0])];

this code returns me the index of selected row, do you know how to combine those two codes?

Comment: Why doesn't _pickerData[row] not work? What's not working about it

Comment: @souldshined it tells me "use of undeclared identifier 'row', did you mean 'pow?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a UIPickerView you can inspect its `selectedRowInComponent:` to determine which item the user has selected. Assuming you populated this picker view from an array you can get the item out if this array using the index returned here. Also assuming that you have a PickerView with only a list of cities pass 0 for the component. The component is there for more complex views like a time picker where you have hours, minutes, and AM/PM.

Comment: so if i do like this   

    self.LabelForSwitch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @([self.PickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] )];

it just return the row i have selected but not the name. 

Do you know how to select the name and pass it to this function ?

(void)getCurrent:(NSString *)query